# Why date format dd/MM/yy shows a time as well?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use "dd/MM/yy" but it shows a time as well.

How it could be?

For example "dd MMMM, yyyy" doesn't show any time.

Thanks!!!

CODE

```
  var completeDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: Not possible with what you've posted.  Where are you seeing the time?

Comment: No time is shown when I test it.  Please post the output you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: Also post the code where you output or modify `completeDate`, please.

Comment: It works for me and displays `"04.10.12"` when I enter `?System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")` in the immediate window of VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option.  It's doesn't include time, keeps everything on one line.. and lets you keep slashes in your format string.

```
string a = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you DO NOT want the time in format, you could use the standard format 'd', according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).  If you look through their [Standard Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) you will see that there is a way to change cultural info as well to get what you want.

```
var completeDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

EDIT Added:

To answer the question as to why your slash is not working... ["The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfoDateSeparator property of the current or specified culture.  If the "/" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it is interpreted as a standard date and time format specifier and throws a FormatException. For more information about using a single format specifier, see Using Single Custom Format Specifiers later in this topic."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

```
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2008, 3, 15);
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");      
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d", culture));  // Displays 15/3/2008
```

EDIT to address comments:  To answer the question as to why you are getting a time format, is that the default culture info on your computer is not matching up with the format string that you put in.  I cannot find why, but I also do not know what culture your computer is set to.  When this happens it MIGHT default back to the general ShortTime format, or "g", which would include the time as well, and is what you get when you do DateTime.ToString(), but it SHOULD have thrown a FormatException.

I added this last part as sort of an actual answer, though I see that as I spend time to get references to ACTUALLY answer the question is worthless... If that is all someone wants, then they should not ask questions that require an answer like this.

Comment: Note the date format will not be the same across all systems in this case.

Comment: Yep that would work. Still though, the OP's code *should* work so this doesn't answer the question of why the custom format doesn't work (if it's actually broken).

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir found it!  Posted why.

Comment: The OP says that the *time* is showing. I think what you found explains what Olivier Jacot-Descombes showed in the comments, but can you explain how it would make the time show?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir I can't answer that entirely.  I can speculate that whatever culture info he is using is tossing the format back to a general format (ShortDateTime or "g"), but I would expect that if this were the case he would get a FormatException.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir Turns out he doesn't want an anwer, he wanted a solution.

Comment: Well, +1 for effort anyways. :) I still want to know why, though!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a time string why not just use `DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yy")`